# Timesyncd not syncing with ntp server

Tags: ntp, systemd-timesyncd

I am using a embedded board which runs a DHCP client with systemd-networkd service. Here I have requirement to fetch ntp server with option 42 and synchronize time from it for every 32 seconds. I was able to do this with systemd-networkd and systemd-timesyncd service. Currently my issue is time is syncing with server only at the start up / reboot , if I modify the time in ntp server I do not see any change in the client until I reboot.
Also status of systemd-timesyncd service shows idle.

I tried to set RootDistanceMaxSec=5 , PollIntervalMinSec=32 in **timesyncd.conf** but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions on this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> if I modify the time in ntp server I do not see any change in the client

That is how it should be!

A well designed NTP client stops trusting an NTP server when the server proves to be erratic / unreliable.

Comment: NTP server time may change at any time so in this case how do I ensure NTP client is in sync with the NTP server? And how will I test the synchronization period of 32 sec?

Comment: The time of an ntp server that is reliable should not “change at any time” ; NTP uses UTC so there are no daylight savings time leaps and if an ntp server needs to make changes they should be extremely small and gradual , not abrupt and or big adjustments.